# deferred execution celery task

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I want to put a task to celery, but I want the task is executed after 30 seconds instead of executed immediately.

For example:

```
@celery.task
def task():
    # waiting 30 seconds
    do something....
```

I can use it to make it: `sleep(30)`, but is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be for that task's task to be to schedule the real task in 30 seconds. Something like that:

```
@celery.task
def task():
    RealTask.apply_async(countdown=30)
```

Comment: I check the [celery document](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/_modules/celery/app/task.html#Task.apply_async)  the `countdown` option also can work. Is it right?